# SEO: Is forcing a request to WWW.example.com from example.com a bad idea?

Tags: htaccess, seo

I have an htaccess file that is forcing the URL request to www. instead of a bare hostname (this is to resolve SSL issues I'm facing that are fixed when you visit the site via www.)

Is this a bad idea in the SEO world?

Comment: Are you using a permanent redirect?

Comment: A 301 code, yes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's been a lot of discussion involving this same issue (try a quick Google search about it). And it mostly comes down to [canonicalization](http://www.searchenginejournal.com/canonicalization-seo-should-i-use-www-or-not/6950/) in order for this to be successful.

Comment: Good link, explains exactly what I needed to know. So it appears a 301 to the www. version *is* the best idea. Thanks @jerluc!

Comment: @Di-0xide Well, not specifically the `www` version. The www-less version is also fine. The real point is to pick one and be consistent about it.

Answer (score 1):

> Is is a bad idea in the SEO world?

No. In fact it's a good idea. Not only for your SSL issues but for SEO. Forcing the users to the "www' (or no www) is good usability as it offers consistency. It also reduces the chances that your pages will be found using two technically different URLs which can result in duplicate issues affecting your rankings.